# Android Emulator Keyboard not launching

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio

I tried to launch the Nexus 6 Emulator. But unfortunately the soft keyboard does not work. I have already unchecked the "Enable Keyboard input" checkbox. Any help would be useful.

Comment: Can somebody help me with this issue

Comment: Please help in this issue

Comment: I tried searching for all the available content on net but nothing worked for me. So if anyone is faced any similar issue kindly help

Comment: I recommend you to use a real device. The emulator is to slow for development.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: you should check it not uncheck it